# Error occuring in C# exe file but not in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, oracle, combobox, exe

When I run the program through Visual Studio 2010, then it works just fine, however, when I run the .exe in the Debug folder, it breaks. I am using C# WinForms connecting to an Oracle Lite database. This is the code in the program:

```
private void discountDescriptionComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateDiscount();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

private void UpdateDiscount()
    {
        try
        {
            //Geting the DiscountId
            int id = int.Parse(cboDiscount.SelectedValue.ToString());
            //dt = your data. You better know about your datasource. I assume there can be a datatable
            DataRow[] dr = this.nISSANDataset.Tables["Discount"].Select("DiscountID = " + id.ToString());
            txtDiscount.Text = dr[0]["DiscountPercent"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

When I run the .exe, this error occurs when I change the discount in the combobox:

"Column 'DiscountID' is constrained to be unique. Value '5' is already present."

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.ConstraintException: Column 'DiscountID' is constrained to be unique.  Value '5' is already present.
   at System.Data.UniqueConstraint.CheckConstraint(DataRow row, DataRowAction action)
   at System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent)
   at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException)
   at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecord(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean fireEvent, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged)
   at System.Data.DataRow.EndEdit()
   at System.Data.DataRowView.EndEdit()
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.EndCurrentEdit()
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(Int32 newPosition, Boolean validating, Boolean endCurrentEdit, Boolean firePositionChange, Boolean pullData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.set_Position(Int32 value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Kirk Rowe ISDP NISSAN v1.0.0.0.4
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Data/C%23%20Projects/Kirk%20Rowe%20ISDP%20NISSAN%20v1.0.0.0.4/Kirk%20Rowe%20ISDP%20NISSAN%20v1.0.0.0.4/bin/Debug/Kirk%20Rowe%20ISDP%20NISSAN%20v1.0.0.0.4.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Accessibility
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Comment: does the program connect to the same database in both debug and release?

Comment: I don't think we are seeing all the relevant code here, and also I would bet that if you open in VS and select several different values in the combobox you will encounter the same error. Something, somewhere is unexpectedly (to you) trying to insert new rows in the database.

Comment: The program and the debug are both connected to the same database. As for the possibility of code happening later on, the User Control that this is happening in doesn't have any saving to the database in regards to that. Only for completely separate tables. As for running it in VS and recreating the error, it just doesn't happen.